# Join pivot table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I need to do a join on. One, the headers I need are actually in the fields. After much playing around I figured out this below. I was really excited because it was running, but then to my dismay I realized it only has the headers from the table [GM].[dbo].[PKT]. It is missing all fields from table a ([GM].[dbo].[CMPLX]). How do I show fields from table a? Also, I tried to only show certain fields from table p, but it would only work if I did - Select * From in the pivot section.

```
With GM1 AS (
Select TOP 10 a.[CMPLX_NBR],
  a.[SYSTEM_ID],
  a.[PKT_TYP_CD],
  a.[CATEG_CD],
  a.[SUPPLR_CD],
  a.[TRANS_CD],
  a.[PRIORITY_INT],
  a.[PRIORITY_INT_EXPR_DT],
  a.[RQSTR_NBR],
  a.[TMSTMP],
p.[PKT_DTTM]
FROM [GM].[dbo].[CMPLX] as a
INNER JOIN [GM].[dbo].[PKT] as p
ON a.[CMPLX_NBR] = p.[CMPLX_NBR]
)

SELECT *
FROM [GM].[dbo].[PKT]
PIVOT (
    sum([PKT_ATTR_CNT])
        For [PKT_ATTR_CD]
        IN (not_sent, not_sent, other, appl, avg, max, min, sum, sent, why)
        )AS GM1Pivot;
```

Comment: Perhaps because you're selecting from your table and not your CTE? i.e. `SELECT * FROM [GM].[dbo].[PKT] PIVOT...` instead of `SELECT * FROM GM1 PIVOT...`?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I cannot believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In the PIVOT operator, we indicate only the aggregation and spreading elements, but not the grouping   element.    T-SQL identify the grouping element  by elimination.    This is the reason why we use a CTE (3 elements (columns) only) before to use PIVOT.
 A CTE should have only these elements:

1. the grouping column ([CMPLX_NBR])
2. the spreading column ([PKT_TYP_CD]),
3. the aggregate column ([PKT_ATTR_CNT]).